# Riemannian metric and Volume form for $SE(n)$ and/or $E(n)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I wonder what happens when you construct the Tiling spaces considering the natural action of $SE(n)$ or $E(n)$ rather than $\mathbb R^n$. In order to do that, I need to understand both the (left invariant) riemannian metric, and the volume form of the considered group. Are they unique?

Could you suggest an example based reference on Lie groups?

Answer (score 1):

Of course any left invariant metric with respect the  group of orientation preserving  euclidean isometries (I believe that it what you call SE(n) )
is a multiple of the standard Euclidean metric and any  invariant 
volume form  is  a multiple of the standard volume  form.

I do not really know what reference to suggest you basing on your question. Actually, your question belongs IMHO rather to the elementary geometry than to the Lie group theory and if I may I suggest you ``Geometry I, II'' of M. Berger.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your answer doesn't say too much to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, your comment does not say too much to me either. Where the desired volume form and left invariant metric  lives? On $R^n$ or on E(n) resp. SE(n)?   In the second case, the volume form is unique, up to scaling. But then I change my answer for the left invariant metric: fixing a positively definite  quadratic form at the Lie algebra gives a left invarinat metric.